# create the authorize filter with parameter asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to develop an authorize filter in asp.net mvc.I have got five categories of users in my site and my site uses custom created authentication system.Now i have a controller action which  should be accessible to 3 out of those five type of users.How to create a filter (basically authorize) and use it which  fulfills my requirement?I think i need to create the authorize filter with parameter.I should be able to use something like this.

Authorize[UsersType="admin,accountant,operator"]

technology used : Asp.net MVC

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

1. Create an Attribute class that Inherits the AuthorizeAttribute class of MVC.
2. Create a constructor in your attribute class that accepts the parameter `UsersType`
3. Override the appropriate methods of AuthorizeAttribute that is needed.
4. Parse the parameter in your appropriate override method.

---

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute :AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string[] _userType { get; set; }

    public AuthorizeUserAttribute(string UsersType)
    {
        // parse your usertypes here.
    }

    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // do the appropriate assigning and authorizing of methods here
        ....
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Now you can put an attribute in your Method in your controller

```
[AuthorizeUser("admin,accountant,operator")]
public ActionMethod Index()
{
    return View();
}
```